Passing visualforce page variable to component in hierachy
I have 2 visualforce pages and a component
2visualforce pages deatils are below

TestVfp,    testPage2

Component

testComponent

In TestVfp, Fetching logoutRedirectURL from testController Apex Class
<apex:page controller="testController">
<apex:composition template="testPage2" >
    -----Content---
</apex:composition>
 <a  href="" onclick="logout('{!logoutRedirectURL}');" >Logout</a>
</apex:page>

Anothervisualforce page :- testPage2
<apex:page>
 <!-- Need to pass logoutRedirectURL here -->
  <c:testComponent>
</apex:page>

testComponent
    <!-- Finally I need to pass logoutRedirectURL here -->
   <a href="" onclick="logout('{!logoutRedirectURL}');">Logout</a>

How to pass logoutRedirectURL from TestVfp to testComponent without writing apex class and without changing the current structure

The absolute minimal change that would work would be to communicate through JavaScript.
<apex:page controller="testController">
  <apex:composition template="testPage2" >
    -----Content---
  </apex:composition>
  <script>
    window.logoutRedirectURL = "{!logoutRedirectURL}";
  </script>
</apex:page>

<!-- Finally I need to pass logoutRedirectURL here -->
<a href="#" onclick="logout(window.logoutRedirectURL);">Logout</a>

Be aware that you're polluting the global window state, so use this with care.
The appropriate method would be to instead reuse the controller, if possible, in the component:
<apex:component controller="testController">
   <a href="" onclick="logout('{!logoutRedirectURL}');">Logout</a>
</apex:component>

This change should require no extra Apex code to be written, depending on how testController is designed.

I have more than 1000 lines of code in testController , just because of this variable i need to reuse the entier class... so what you recommend ?

@SFDCLearner Without seeing the code, I don't know what to recommend for your specific case. My preference would be to refactor logoutRedirectURL to a new class, and use it as an extension. However, if you don't want that, reusing testController is probably acceptable; only the constructor, static code, and methods you call run, which may have good performance. Otherwise, the JavaScript solution will also work just fine, it just takes some planning to avoid collisions in the global variable scope.
